# desplazamiento de la barra en eclipse ide

Tags: java, eclipse

hola tengo una consulta al momento de ejecutar el proyecto que hago en el eclipse quiero evitar que el scroll vertical baje directamente a la ultima linea como se puede ver en este caso [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
lo que quiero es que el scroll se mantenga en la parte superior al momento que le inyecte todo el texto

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.